# how can i set a csrf token in FormData sended with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send to Django this FormData that way:

```
const form = new FormData()

form.append('name','Vitor')
form.append('age',20)
form.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');

const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('POST','my_form')
request.send(form)

request.onload = function(){
 alert('sucess')   
}
request.onerror = function(){
    alert('error')   
   }
```

in Django:

```
def my_form(request):
    ob = request.POST
    print('name: '+ ob['name'], 'age: '+ob['age'])
    return redirect('/')
```

but the console gives me:

```
[30/Jun/2020 20:27:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 419
[30/Jun/2020 20:27:12] "GET /static/script.js HTTP/1.1" 200 352
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /my_form
[30/Jun/2020 20:27:12] "POST /my_form HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

What can i do to set the CSRF token in this request?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, i was using an embed static javascript:

```
<script src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
```

the {{ csrf_token }} of the django template language just returns his value when it's in html, so the script needs to be:

```
<script>
////the code here
</script>
```